# python's equivalent of __file__ in julia?

Tags: julia

I want to program something python like:

```
import os

ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

but in Julia?

So far `println(__FILE__)` did not work.

Answer (score 4):

Julia's [docs](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/file/) on file system tell to use the macro:

```
ROOT = dirname(@__FILE__)
```